# Finite multiplicative group of matrices with sum of traces equal to zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, contest-math

Let  $G=\{M_1,M_2,...,M_k\}$ be a finite set such that $ M_i\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $(G,\;\cdot\:)$ is a group with matrix multiplication. If $\sum _{i=1}^k \operatorname{tr} (M_i)=0$ then how to prove $\sum _{i=1}^k M_i=0$ ?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff: i try to prove A=$\sum _{i=0}^k M_i$ is nil-potent or idempotent  by $\{M_1,M_2,...,M_k\}=G=\{M_iM_1,M_iM_2,...,M_iM_k\}$ but i couldn't do it

Comment: @julien:hi i complete my idea like you but it  has small different thanks so much

Comment: Your idea was great, especially if you came up with it on your own. I was aware of the trick, so I have no merit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $M:=\sum_{i=1}^kM_i$. For each $i$, $M\longmapsto M_iM$ induces a bijection of $G$ onto itself. So
$$
M^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^kM_iM_j=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^kM_j=\sum_{i=1}^kM=kM.
$$
Therefore $E=\frac{1}{k}M$ is idempotent, i.e. $E^2=E$. As is well-known, in characteristic $0$, the rank of an idempotent equals its trace. Just diagonalize to check this fact. So
$$
\mbox{rank}E=\mbox{trace}\frac{1}{k}M=\frac{1}{k}\mbox{trace}M=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k\mbox{trace}M_i=0.
$$
Thus $E=0$, whence $M=0$.

**(Not exactly relevant) note:** this is a standard trick in group algebras, in particular. See [these notes](http://www.univ-orleans.fr/mapmo/membres/chatterji/Valette.pdf) by Alain Valette, p.11 et seq. for related results. In particular, note that Higson and Kasparov proved that the complex group algebra $\mathbb{C}\Gamma$ has no nontrivial idempotents when $\Gamma$ is torsion-free and a-T-menable (i.e. has the [Haagerup property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haagerup_property)), as an application of their work on the Baum-Connes conjecture. Apparently, this is still not accessible by algebraic tools. It is conjectured that this is true for any torsion-free group. That's called [Kaplansky's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky%27s_conjecture).

Comment: The results mentioned in your note of course do not apply to the case at hand, though, which has lots of torsion and, in fact, lots of non-trivial idempotents :-)

Answer (score 7):

The group acts in a natural way on $\mathbb R^n$, and the hypothesis is that if $\chi$ is character afforded by that representation, then $\chi$ is orthogonal to the character of the trivial module. It follows from standard results on characters that the representation on $\mathbb R^n$ does not have any trivial subrepresentation.
Since the group acts trivially on the image of the map $\sum_iM_i:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, this map must be zero. This is precisely the conclusion you seek.

Comment: Of course, all this is incomprehensible if one does not know the basics of character theory :-) Let it count as motivation to learn it!