# The spectrum of $M$ is included in $\{ 0,k \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $k \geq 1$ and let $S=\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k \}$ be a subset of $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, such that $I_n \in S$. Also, if $X \in S$, then $X^{-1} \in S$ and if $X,Y \in S$, then $XY \in S$. Let $$M=A_1+A_2+\dots+A_k$$
>   Prove that the only eigenvalues of $M$ are from the set $\{0,k \}$.

I am not sure if the statement is entirely correct. It seems like for $k=3$ and $S=\{I_n,A,A^{-1} \}$ the conclusion doesn't hold. I'm wondering if there is a correction that could be made, or maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Note that the set $S$ needs to be closed under both inversions and products. $S = \{I, A, A^{-1}\}$ will usually not satisfy the conditions, unless $A$ has the special property that $A^2 = A^{-1}$. (If $A^2 = I$, then $A^{-1} = A$ and so this is multiplicatively closed, but is really a set of size 2, not 3).

Comment: Ohh right! I totally missed the possibility that $X=Y$ in the hypothesis. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* Since $S$ is a finite multiplicative subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$, we must have $A_jS=S$ for every $j$. Now, what is $M^2$?

Related: [Finite multiplicative group of matrices with sum of traces equal to zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376460)

Comment: Right. $M^2=kM$ and the conclusion follows. Thank you!